# Home automation connection for gas fireplace

Tags: fireplace, gas, home-automation

What, specifically, is needed to bring home automation (HomeKit) to a remote electronic ignition system with inputs for just this type of behavior but no instructions on how to do so?

Whatever the solution is would connect to the device via the 'panel' connector in "figure 2" and somehow control those relays(?).

[image: Product External Source Operation Guide]

*Side note: feel free to move this to a more appropriate Stack Exchange forum if this question rubs the Home Improvement moderators the wrong way.*

Comment: Are you looking to simply connect an off the shelf device, or do you want to roll your own solution?

Comment: Also, are you comfortable working with (low voltage) electronics?

Comment: Either way. Willing to try and Raspberry Pi it if I have to. Just looking at options – any/all of them.  I really just want to say "Siri, turn on the fireplace"

Comment: If you can find something like [this](http://smartenit.com/product/ezio4o/) that works with the official Insteon hubs, that's probably your best bet.